# Does ordering of mesh element change from run to run for constrained triangulation under CGAL?

Tags: mesh, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I iterate over `finie_vertieces`, `finite_edges` and `finite_faces` after generating constrained delauny triangulation with Loyd optimization. I am on VS2012 using CGAL 4.12 under release mode. I see for a given case `finite_verices` list is repeatable (so is the vertex list under `finite_faces`), however, the ordering of the edges in `finite_edges` seems to change from run to run

```
for(auto eit = cdtp.finite_edges_begin(); eit != cdtp.finite_edges_end(); ++eit)
{

    const auto isConstrainedEdge  = cdtp.is_constrained(*eit);
    auto & cFace = *(eit->first);
    auto cwVert = cFace.vertex(cFace.cw(eit->second));
    auto ccwVert = cFace.vertex(cFace.ccw(eit->second));
```

I use the above code snippet to extract vertex list, and vertex list with a given edge changes from run to run.
Any help is appreciated resolving this, as I am looking for consistent behavior in the code. My triangulation involves many line constraints on a two dimensional domain.

Answer (score 2):

I was [told](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Simultaneous-iteration-over-duplicate-triangulations-td4659640.html#a4659655) it's likely dependable behaviour, but there is no guarantee of order. IIRC the documentation says the traversal order is not guaranteed. I think it's best to assume the iterators' transversal is not deterministic and could change.

You could use any of the [_info extensions](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__face__base__with__info__2.html) to embed information into the face, edge, etc (a hash perhaps?) which you could then check against to detect a change.

In my use case, I wanted to traverse the mesh in parallel and OpenMP didn't support the iterators. So I hold a vector of the Face_handles in memory which I can then easily index over. In conjunction with the _info data, you could use this to build a vector of edges,faces, etc with a guaranteed order using unique information in the `->info()` field.

Another [_info example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2terrain_with_info_8cpp-example.html).